# Garbage collection when final variables used in anonymous classes

Tags: java, garbage-collection, final

If I have code similar to the following:

```
public Constructor(final Object o) {
    taskSystem.add(new CycleTask(15, 15, -1) {

        @Override
        public void execute() throws Throwable {
            //access o here every 15 cycles forever
        }
    });
}
```

When would o be garbage collected, if ever? Only when the task has been collected, or will it remain in memory forever because it's final?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`o` *might* get garbage collected once it is not reachable any longer, whether it is final or not. Obviously, as long as `execute` is running, if it needs to access `o`, it will prevent GC.

When `execute` is done running, and assuming you have not stored any references to `o` (for example in a collection), it will be flagged as ready for garbage collection.

Answer (score 5):

When the anonymous class instance becomes eligible for garbage collection, if nothing else refers to the object that `o` referred to when the method was called, that object will become eligible for garbage collection.

There's nothing special about final variables which deters garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

'final' has no effect on GC. The object will become eligible for collection when it becomes unreachable. In this case there are at least three references, any one of which can stop that: the 'final' parameter, which disappears when the method returns; the caller's reference; and the copy of the final variable in the anonymous class instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship between `final` keyword and the lifetime of the variable.

It will be garbage collected when not needed anymore, and since it's a parameter this can happen just outside the method (if there is no reference outside).

The `final` keyword is just a constraint given to the compiler to forbid any further modification of the reference `o` after the call of the function.

Comment: That's not very well expressed. 'Living space' should be 'lifetime'. Obviously the caller of the method must have had a reference, and the anonymous class instance has another. The 'final' keyword forbids any modification to that *variable* after initialization, *during* the method execution, which is its entire scope.