# How do final fields NOT leak memory?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, final

I have been, without a question, using the `final` keyword for years to denote fields that should not change for the lifetime of an instance/class. Suddenly this occured to me...

So given this example:

```
public class TestFinalGC{

    private TestFinalGC(){}

    private final Object obj = new Object();

     public static void main(String []args){
         TestFinalGC instance = new TestFinalGC();
         // instance Ref -> actual instance ->? obj ref-> actual obj
         System.out.println(instance.obj);
         instance = null;
         //say GC makes sweep here... what happens?
         //lets assume theres more code, obj would obviously be eligible for GC on app exit.
     }
}
```

How does the `obj` member NOT leak here? Are `final` fields automatically WeakReferences such that if the strong references to parent(s) are nulled, they are eligible for garbage collection?

[The JLS does not seem to note anything special about final](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

**Update:**

So this question of mine was founded on the premise that "reachability" and strong/weak references are closely related. There is [this confusing oracle doc on reachability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability) that leads me to believe that nested references should always be "strongly reachable". Hence, I do null my nested object references in all my objects, but it appears that this obviously should not be the case from all of the comments I am receiving.

So regarding "reachability", then, is it simply just that nested object references are no longer considered "reachable" if parent references are no longer reachable?

It <s>could be</s> is true that the premise of this problem is incorrect, but there is still intriguing information to consolidate here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbage collection when final variables used in anonymous classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841674/garbage-collection-when-final-variables-used-in-anonymous-classes)

Comment: @Makoto uh. we're not talking about anonymous classes here. those behave differently?

Comment: No, but the answers are still valid.  There isn't anything special about `final` that makes it ineligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @Makoto well I question the quality of those answers. Objects are DEFINED as eligible for garbage collection once they are no longer strongly reachable. We all know `final` does not allow you to assign to the variable more than once, so there is no way to clear that nested strong reference (if it is a strong reference, that is). So technically speaking, if the final field WAS in fact a strong reference that referred to another object, wouldn't we have a problem?

Comment: @rpg711 Only if you exclude reachability. When the final field itself is no longer reachable, it becomes eligible for GC. At that point, everything that it refers to becomes unreachable and potentially eligible (unless, for example, it's reachable through another reference).

Comment: @rpg711 Before assigning instance to null, the GC graph looks like Root --> instance --> obj. On assigning instance to null, the link between Root and instance is broken. Hence both instance and obj become eligible for garbage collection. I'm not sure how 'final' can make a difference here.

Comment: `final` guarantees that the `Object` being pointed to does not become eligible for GC until the object containing the reference is GCed. It may become eligible then, or later, but that's not an issue of class `TestFinalGC` any more.

Comment: @aquaraga so are you saying that when the `Root -> instance` reference is cleared, the final field automatically becomes a weak reference? By definition a strong reference cannot be GC'd. Actually, if this is the case, perhaps I have been misunderstanding how references work all along. I actually go and manually null every single nested reference to destroy my objects. This is also the reason why the premise of the question involves final fields, because you can't clear those.

Comment: When `Root->instance` is cleared, the instance that contains the final field is no longer reachable, and therefore whatever the final field refers to is also no longer reachable, provided nothing else refers to it.  Being unreachable is not the same as being a weak reference.

Comment: You can see objects as villages, and references as single-way roads from one village to another. If you can only go to the village B using a road from village A, and if there is no road leading to village A anymore (i.e. A is unreachable), then of course village B is not reachable anymore either. And the GC will thus collect A and B.

Comment: @JBNizet the whole concept of nested references being unreachable when the parent object is no longer reachable is intuitively and definitively correct to me as well, I mean, that's one of the conditions where as defined, objects are eligible for GC. But I recently delved deeper into the concept of references, and that is more or less where I got caught up, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Makoto suggested, there is simply nothing special about `final` in variable declarations as far as GC is concerned. In your example code

```
private final Object obj = new Object();
```

will be garbage collected at the same time as

```
private Object obj = new Object();
```

Both are strong references, but are invalidated and garbage collected together with their parent class `TestFinalGC` instance. That is because when the instance is GC'd, the reference fields are destroyed as well and the references do not exist any more. obj's reference count thus decreases by one.

However, should you write something like

```
Object x = myTestFinalGC.obj; // only works if your obj is not private, of course
```

Then the object will not be garbage collected because it will still have one reference lingering around (assuming this particular line of code is in another class instance that remains alive when myTestFinalGC is garbage collected.

tl;dr: memory allocations are garbage collected when their hard reference count drops to zero (and the collector runs, of course). `final` doesn't change this fact.

Comment: *memory allocations are garbage collected when their hard reference count drops to zero*: no, that's incorrect. Reachability is what matters, not reference counts. Otherwise, the GC would never collect graphs of objects with cyclic references.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple to explain the concept. OP seems to have issues understanding conditions for GC. So I didn't want to further complicate stuff with that. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @velis I wouldn't say issues, more just that the premise that this problem is founded upon is quite possibly incorrect. I also want to note that I am not exactly looking for simple. For a while, I also was under the belief that objects that are not reachable are eligible for GC, and nested objects are not reachable when their parents are no longer reachable. But I delved deeper into what that meant, and a deeper explanation of how this stuff works would actually be quite enlightening for me.

Comment: Indeed the premise is incorrect. `final` will only tell the compiler to prevent any further assignmnets to the varaiable, but it will not make the reference any stronger or put the reference into a special list that will never be garbage collected. I suspect you at some point thought `final` causes that.

Comment: @velis well, intuitively that is rather ridiculous to me as well, because I would have crazy amounts of memory leaks in just about all the projects I have worked on if this sort of behavior actually did exist. But then there's the oracle doc on reachability that I linked to that further confused me and lead me to begin to doubt that "obvious" truth.

Comment: I must say that reading all the comments in this question leaves me wondering what of your question still remains unexplained to you. It seems you are accepting the explanations, but something still doesn't align for you. Can you specify it?

Comment: @velis Excuse my lack of etiquette ;). You have adequately answered the question as it stands so you get the accept. If you could perhaps go into more depth as to what exactly happens under the covers here, I think there could be more than just me that benefits.

Comment: I wasn't hinting for an answer accept. The question was genuine because I can see that you still don't have all the Legos in the right places. I was hoping that you could point at just the pieces that still don't work for you.

Comment: @velis I can say now, definitively, at a high level, that any object that is no longer reachable is eligible for GC. So I can extend this to say that nested object references are no longer reachable and are thus eligible for GC when their parent object is no longer reachable. I understand all of this. The question I still have is "is this as deep as I can hope to understand this GC behavior, and if not, what would be an explanation look like one level deeper?" A selfish question, because everything does click, so that is why I did accept your answer :)

Comment: I see. I must admit I never delved into GC as far as to be able to explain it even further. I found later comments by JB Nizet, kjkrum and aquaraga very informative and complete. I'm not even sure thare is a *one level deeper* explanation. GC is a simple concept, otherwise it would be too costly to implement.